# Not able to invoke ExternalInterface method of flash using (watir-)webdriver

Tags: flash, webdriver, externalinterface, watir-webdriver

I am trying to use automate a web + flash application. Our dev have provided me ExternInterface APIs, which we are able to invoke using Watire and IE. However same thing is now working on FF 3.6 and watir-webdriver/webdriver/firewatir. I am tending to assume that this is not a problem with either of the automation tool, but FF itself. However other part of our product uses js to invoke other APIs and they are working fine. So I am not able to zero in on browser or automation tool.

Any hints?

Thanks for the help.

-Manish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably is because of the way you are embedding your swf on your webpage.

FF/Chrome use `<object>` tags whereas IE uses `<embed>` tags.

This is probably where you have missed out.

You should use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) for embedding your swf and handling this kind of cross-browser embedding problems for you.

Oh, and dont forget to flag `allowScriptAccess` to true.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the hints. We are complying with all the points mentioned by you.